# How do you write a observer child component as a class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

For what I'm trying to achieve I need to be able to run `componentDidMount()` within a child component.
How can I rewrite `const Child = observer(({ doc }) => {` as a class component?

I'm pulling data from firebase and iterating that data into the child component. Assume everything works properly and I just want to rewrite the child component.

If my logic is flawed, please let me know.

```
const Parent = observer(
  class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
          <View>
            {latestEP.docs.map(doc => (
              <Child key={doc.id} doc={doc} ref={this.load} />
            ))}
          </View>
      )
    }
  }
)

const Child = observer(({ doc }) => {
  const { name, id, date, url, description } = doc.data;

  return (
    //some stuff
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the `Child` component into a class just like you have done for the `Parent` component, making sure you get the `doc` prop from `this.props`.

```js
const Child = observer(
  class Child extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      // ...
    }

    render() {
      const { name, id, date, url, description } = this.props.doc.data;

      return (
        // some stuff
      );
    }
  }
);
```